# Multiple button click handling

Tags: jquery, json

In my html page I have 4 buy buttons. On clicking each button corresponding datas will be populated in a popup. Its working fine. But among these 4 buttons two are having same data. So I dont need a separate call to get this data. I want to check whether the data is already loaded there in the page and if yes that needs to be populated. I'm using ajax with JSON for fetching data from back end. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Adding the fiddle

Here if u check using firbug>Net at the bottom we can see 4 json responses happened already loaded. I need to avoid this, because all these four resposes are duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using jquery ajax you can simply let jQuery do the caching work.

```
$.ajax({

    cache: true,

    success: function(data) {

        // do something now that the data is loaded

    },

    url: '/path/to/my/json/file.js'

});
```

Comment: Thanks Tosh for the quick response. But caching I tried but is not useful in my case. All these responses are coming at the page load itself. In firebug I can see the response coming for the 4 buttons

Comment: Hmhm to be honest I haven't looked into caching with jQuery Ajax, could it it cached at browser level? does that explain th page load? The other way to cache it is store it in the memory, but you don't want to overload the memory, or add it to the html page and set it to display none and check if it exists otherwise make an ajax request.

Comment: more on jquery caching: http://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/08/07/ajax-caching-two-important-facts/

Answer (score 0):

I would have used jQuery and made something general :

```
$('.buybutton').click(function() {
    loadDataIfNotLoaded();
 });
```

Just put the class="buybutton" to each buy button and do the check if data is loaded into your function.

Comment: After the first time you loaded data, why don't you check if $('#code').text contains data already before doing the request ? Or maybe trying HTTP cache like Tosh said. Both should work.